# Issue with editText inside a ScrollView getting hidden by the InputKeyboard

Tags: android, input, android-edittext, scrollview

Hej,

I am having a editText for the user to enter his location and this resides within a ScrollView. When the user clicks inside it i want the scrollview to scroll just below the editText field and the keyboard to appear as well.

Now what i get is :

[EditText is Hidden](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UaqHR.png)

The code part that sets the scrollview is :

```
        final int[] location = {0, 0};
    final int[] locationScroll = {0, 0};
                keywordsedittext.getLocationInWindow(location);
            mainScroll.getLocationInWindow(locationScroll);
                float px = Utils.pixelsFromDP(keywordsedittext.getPaddingTop(), PropertyMainMenuActivity.this);
            location[1] = (int) (location[1] - locationScroll[1] - px);
                mainScroll.smoothScrollTo(0, location[1]);
            ((LockableScrollView) mainScroll).setScrollingEnabled(false);

            keywordsedittext.setFocusable(true);
            keywordsedittext.requestFocusFromTouch();
            InputMethodManager lManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            lManager.showSoftInput(keywordsedittext, 0);
```

So basically the scrollview scrolls to the Y height coordinate of the editText (top padding removed).
But when the code gets executed, the input text area of the editText gets hidden by the keyboard input.

How should i procceed with this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Use this in your manifest

```
<activity android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"> </activity>
```

adjustPan movesthe page content without resizing it

For more info
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your ScrollView xml:

```
android:fillViewport="true"
```

Add this in the Manifest.xml

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

And you should be good to go.